# P - Selection makes mesh disappear

Tags: mesh, selection-tools

I have a house and I want to separate the floor so that I can apply a different material. Now the problem is that when I go to edit mode and press "P" and "Selection" the floor disappears it creates a new cube, but there is no selectable mesh anymore.

Can someone point me in the right direction as to what could be happening? Thanks

Image 1
Object Selected

Image 2 Edit mode, face selected

Image 3 Everything vanished after p-Selection

[image: Object Selected]
[image: Edit mode, face selected]
[image: Everything vanished after p-Selection]

Comment: Without seeing any images of your scene and layout it's impossible to say. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: I have now added images, hopefully that helps to show what I mean

Comment: If you can share the blend file with the already separated floor to see where the problem is, it might help you.

Comment: The blend can be downloaded here: https://easyupload.io/gk40dg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two boolean modifiers on the floor left over from the original model. Remove them and the floor will show again.

[image]

Comment: The floor has come back, thank you for that. But the walls disappeared when the p-selection was done, and if I remove the boolean on "cube" the walls come back but windows are then covered by walls. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: I have changed the operator from "exact" to "fast" and it seems to have fixed the issue for the walls. Please let me know if this is the right way of doing it.

Comment: yes, exactly that fixes the problem in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can see here once the boolean are removed the walls also come back but then the windows are hidden. Thanks

[image]